# How are Google Maps API limits enforced in Javascript V3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a site launching using the javascript google maps sdk v3.

I read in the Google Maps site that I'm limited to 25,000 map loads a day; however, when using the SDK I don't provide a key or in any other way identify in the calls that make to load my map (for example, like I do in my android application).

My question is - how do Google really enforce this and know which calls I make?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a key, and you reach the limit for 90 consecutive days - they will contact you about it and ask you to purchase a license (not shut their services down from your site). For more info read [Usage Limits and Billing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage) from the API docs.

Comment: This is exactly what I have a hard time understanding; how do they contact me? They go up to my "About" and write me a mail? And how is measured?

Comment: i am not google's guy, i think they probably track your domain. from domain detail they may contact with which way is available.

Comment: When you don't have a key/you don't use a key they probably will not contact anybody, because they only may know your email when you use the key.  [**Using an API key ....ensures that Google can contact you about your application if necessary**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key)